# Image.FromStream Parameter is not valid

Tags: c#, .net

Environment is `.net framework 4.5`

```
    var fileStream = new FileStream(@"C:\Users\supeng\Downloads\1.png", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);    
    var img = Image.FromStream(fileStream); //thrown Parameter is not valid
```

Dear friends, I have a picture and use the above method to generate the picture. But it gives an error every time. Pictures can be downloaded from the link below

http://dfiles.tms.beisen.com/download/RecruitmentFile/600001/1645522170/6fbab75aeaee4965a58359ba656c1405.png

Comment: the error is `Parameter is not valid` not `thrown Parameter is not valid`. and it means that the fileStream that you're sending to `Image.FromStream` is not valid. you have to debug it to see what's going wrong with your fileStream. it probably isn't accessible or is corrupted.

Comment: I am getting the following exception when I use your image and Image.FromFile - https://i.stack.imgur.com/a1Snz.png

Comment: Your file is _not_ a PNG image even though its extension is mistakenly set to `.png`. If you see it in a file viewer/hex editor it starts with `RIFF####WEBPVP8` suggesting it is actually a [WebP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebP) image. GDI+ does not support this format so you either must convert your image to a real PNG or use a 3rd party [library](https://www.graphicsmill.com/docs/gm/loading-and-saving-animated-webps.htm) to load it as a `System.Drawing.Image`.